# Number of photoelectrons emitted and the intensity of light used

Tags: photoelectric-effect

In photoelectric emission,
"The number of photoelectrons emitted per unit area per unit time is directly proportional to the intensity of light used."
Is this true if the frequency is not held constant? If yes, please explain how.
If a light of frequency f and intensity I emits n photoelectrons from a metal surface(of threshold frequency f/4) per unit area per unit time, how many photoelectrons will be emitted from the same metal surface per unit area per unit time when a lights of frequency and intensity
1)f/2, I
2)2f, 2I
3)f/2, 2I
are separately used.

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/340592/photoelectric-effect-how-can-number-of-electrons-emitted-be-independent-of-freq/340648#340648. If the energy of  a single photon is above the material work function then the number of photoelectrons is equal to (or directly proportional to) the number of photons. For fixed intensity the number of photons is inversely proportional to frequency. For fixed frequency the number of photons is directly proportional to intensity. $N \propto \frac{I}{f}$

Comment: I would say the statement old true for a source with a given spectrum. Once above threshold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the number of photoelectrons is proportional to the light intensity. At a fixed frequency.

The rest of this question is impossible to answer.  The workfunction threshold is given by the OP as $f/4$, so $f$ should be in the far UV. It is then likely that the photoelectric yield is higher at $f/2$. And that it would be lower at $2f$ (likely above the plasmon cutoff).

But photoemission intensities depend on details of the electronic structure of the material: its density of occupied states and also on the final states reached by vertical transitions in $k$-space. And at $2f$ (eight times the work function) there might be emission from a shallow core level.

Answer (score -1):

> The number of photoelectrons emitted per unit area per unit time is directly proportional to the intensity of light used.

is a correct statement. The frequency of the light is proportional to the energy of the light (through $E=hf$) and therefore only affects the kinetic energy of the photoelectrons coming out from the surface not their numbers.

For example, if you use light with low energy (that is low frequency) than the work function of the metal then you can increase the intensity as much as you want; no photoelectrons would be emitted. On the other hand, if you have light with energy higher than the work function of the metal even a very dim light source would emit photoelectrons.

So, the number of electrons emitted is only proportional to the intensity of the light not the energy (or frequency) as long as the energy of the photons is higher then the work function of the metal.

Comment: I correct. Frequency does affect the number of photoelectrons coming out from the surface.

Comment: @Pieter will you also tell how?

Comment: It depends... things go up and down with frequency, depends on material, that is what spectroscopy measures.

Comment: well, I guess what we are talking here is not an XPS, ARPES or an UPS measurement. Of course number of electrons emitted from a core level will depend on photon energy through photoemission cross section etc. In the context of photoelectric effect number of electrons emitted from the surface is independent of the frequency of the light.

Comment: Strange belief. Just google "photocathode spectral response" and you will see the curves.

Comment: I think the context is the point what is important here. I, with my hands, acquired an x-ray absorption spectra in a synchrotron through the measurement of photo current from a sample. There I have seen with my eyes the change in photo current with the change in photon energy. This question is about simple photoelectric effect.

Comment: The appeal to expertise does not really work on me, as I have also worked at synchrotrons. Photoemission at low energies is not simple: strong final-state effects.

Comment: Let's take Au with work function of app. 5 eV as an example. If I send one photon of energy 5.01 eV to Au surface then I kick one electron out, send two photons two electrons come out, etc. However, in reality it maybe the case that the photon is not absorbed by the first layer of atoms on the surface but the second or the third one and the electron lost its energy to the material on the way and never made it out of the material. Shall we then say that Einstein's theory of photoelectric effect is wrong because we send the material a photon with enough energy but a photoelectron never came out?

Comment: So, we simplify the problem and say: one photon with enough energy in one electron out, two photons in two electrons out. Therefore the number of photoelectrons is proportional to light intensity. Now, if I send one photon with energy 10 eV or 20 eV or 30 eV instead still only one photoelectron will come out. Therefore number of photoelectrons does NOT depend on energy (frequency) of the light. It is true that if one increases the photon energy very much then it is possible to emit a core electron plus and Auger electron that is one photon in two electrons out but this is out of context here.

Comment: Firstly, gold is quite reflective at those energies; depending on angle a large part of the incident light is not absorbed. And 10 meV above threshold, very few excited electrons make it out, need to be incident close to normal. The yield will increase when you get a bit higher than the threshold.